# present multiple ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I would like to present/show 2 modalviewcontroller at the same time.
It is possible to show the first one with no animation, and directly the second one with the animation. **This work.**

The problem with this: the first one is shown while the animation of the second one is playing. That's not good.
How can I fix that ?

- The first one fully transparent ? Is that possible, if yes, how ? I tried without success.
- Is it possible to "insert" the first modalviewcontroller below when the second one has ended its animation ? (Like this, when dismissing the second, the first modal will be shown)
- Others ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: You will not be able to make them fully transparent..I think you are best off creating a view and animating it to slide up like a ModalVC if you would like this functionality.

Comment: Hmm yeah that's an alternative I would like to avoid ;P - Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ever look up what "modal" means?

I would suggest making one just a plain old view and use only one view controller at a time as Apple recommends...  at the very least you need to make one of them a plain old view controller, as your hierarchy is all confuzzled when you attempt to present two modal controllers at once...